# I want to record a timestamp in gedit app (open terminator then write "gedit" hit enter)

Tags: linux, time, timestamp, gedit

Is there a away to paste a current timestamp in gedit app in linux? like using hotkey F5 in notepad from Windows?

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask. You should try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a plugin called **Insert Date/Time**, but i don't know if will work with a key. After enabling the plugin in **Preferences/Plugins** menu, you can insert timestamp in doc from **Tools / Insert Date and Time**.

[plugins menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KBmA.png)

[insert date/time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9GRzx.png)